# Is a LINQ loop actually faster or is it just syntactical sugar?

Tags: c#, linq

if a regular for-loop is refactored to a LINQ, are there any benefits on the execution side or is it just syntax?

Comment: Decompile, benchmark, search the web, read, show you understand what you're asking.

Comment: it depends is your answer

Comment: If you want to know which of your horses is faster, race the horses.

Comment: this question is kind of flawed because of the assumption you've made about Linq, in that it is syntactic sugar, while it has syntactic sugar quality, what its doing is giving you the ability to create expression trees, which are a powerful concept that allow you to leverage the linq query type syntax onto many different things

Comment: A linq loop is turning faster :)

Comment: @Nolonar - A bit of an unfair analogy because you need to know who bred/raised the "horses" too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, LinQ is using IEnumerables, so it may be subject to  deferred execution. But a loop does not get faster by using LinQ. It may get faster because using LinQ allows for other optimizations. But that depends on the loop.